How to secure AWS API Gateway with Cognito
I created a Lambda API Gateway and added a Cognito Authorizer. When I test the Authorizer in the console, it works. However when I call the API from my ASP .NET code, I do not need to add any token to the header. I am able to access the API as if there was not any Authorizer.
I have this code to add my token, but I can still access the API even without it:
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);


So I added the Authorizer to the API and assumed it would apply to all methods of the API, but it turns out you have to go to the method request settings to apply the Authorizer.
